# Python logging module: how to save log to a file if (and only if) assertion test fails?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, unit-testing, logging

I am looking for an elegant and *Pythonic* solution, to make tests save a log to a file, though **only** in case of test failure. I would like to keep things simple, and stick with Python's built-in [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module.

My current solution is to use a wrapper function for assert of every test:

```python
import unittest

class superTestCase(unittest.TestCase): 
    ...

    def assertWithLogging(self, assertion, assertion_arguments, expected_response, actual_response, *args):
        try:
            assertion(*assertion_arguments)
        except AssertionError as ae:
            test_name = inspect.stack()[1][3]
            current_date_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y.%m.%d %H-%M-%S")
            logging.basicConfig(filename='tests/{}-{}-Failure.log'.format(current_date_time, test_name),
                                filemode='a',
                                format='%(message)s',
                                level=logging.DEBUG
                                )
            logger = logging.getLogger('FailureLogger')
            logger.debug('{} has failed'.format(test_name))
            logger.debug('Expected response(s):')
            logger.debug(expected_response)
            logger.debug('Actual response:')
            logger.debug(actual_response)
            for arg in args:
                logger.debug('Additionl logging info:')
                logger.debug(arg)
            raise ae

    def testSomething(self):
        ...

        self.assertWithLogging(self.assertEqual,
                               [expected_response, actual_response]
                               expected_response,
                               actual_response,
                               some_other_variable
                               )
```

Though it works as I expect it to, this solution seems clumsy and not too *Pythonic*, to me.

1. What would be (*Is there*) a more elegant way to achieve the same result?
2. What are the downsides of current approach?

Comment: I can't see any way to override the behaviour of all the various assert methods, so a wrapper function may be the best way. That said: (1) You should move basicConfig out of this module altogether (it will not even do anything if the root logger is already configured) and move the getLogger call to the module level; (2) You don't need to capture the current time as the debug calls already produce that (`asctime` field); (3) I don't see the need to repeat expected_response and actual_response - that just makes every call to `assertWithLogging` more verbose.

Comment: @JoeP, thanks for the comment. I have some follow up questions: **(1)** Are you saggesting to move `basicConfig` to a separate module (together with `import logging`, obviously), and then import this module to wherever logger is needed?  **(2)** I use current time, to make it part of the logfile name. Is it possible to use `asctime` as a part of `basicConfig(filename=...)`?  **(3)** Do you propose to log assertion message, instead? Because now, if I'll remove logging of `expected_response` and `actual_response`, only `someTest has failed` will remain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use various logging mechanisms where in you can set the type of logs you want to achieve.

The one below will log only error messages.

```
Logger.error(msg, *args, **kwargs)
```

This logs `msg` with [level](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#levels) `logging.ERROR` on this logger. The arguments are interpreted as for [`debug()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.debug).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I, probably, was not precise enough about what I was asking. I am looking for a way to log some messages (save log to a file actually, which could be considered equivalent, in this case) **only if** assertion of the test fails (regardless of message's `logging.level`). As I can not add `logger` calls inside the assertion itself, I came up withe the wrapper solution, presented in the question. Though I feel it is clumsy, so I am looking for a better alternative. I hope question makes more sense now.