# How to log the name of the test class, if the test method resides in a class common for all tests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, unit-testing, logging

I have the following project structure:

```
/root
  /tests
    common_test_case.py
    test_case_1.py
    test_case_2.py
    ...
  project_file.py
  ...
```

Every test `test_case_...` is inherited from both [`unittest.TestCase`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase) and `common_test_case.CommonTestCase`. Class `CommonTestCase` contains test methods that should be executed by all the tests (though using data unique to each test, stored and accessed in `self.something` of the test). If some specific tests are needed for an exact test case, they are added directly to that particular class.

Currently I am working on adding logging to my tests. Among other things I would like to log the class the method was run from (since the approach above implies the same test method name for different classes). I would like to stick with the built-in [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#module-logging) module to achieve this.

I have tried the following [LogRecord attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes):`%(filename)s`, `%(module)s`, `%(pathname)s`. Though, for methods defined in `common_test_case.py` they all return path/name to the `common_test_case.py` and not the test module they were actually run from.

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to, using only built-in `logging` module?
2. Using some third-party/other module (I was thinking maybe some "hacky" solution with [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html?highlight=inspect#module-inspect))?
3. Is it possible to achieve (in Python) at all?

Comment: How is your logger configured?

Comment: @DroidX86, it is actually a wrapper around the assertion of each test (I did not include the details here to, sort of, "isolate" the question). The code snippet demonstrating the logger configuration is present in [another question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55625965/8554766).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question appears similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14954405/1030244), and solved by:

```
self.id()
```

See the function definition [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Lib/unittest/case.py#L486), which calls `self.__class__` for the instance of the `TestCase` class that is instantiated. Given that you are using multiple inheritance the [multiple inheritance rules from Python](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/classes.html#multiple-inheritance) apply:

> For most purposes, in the simplest cases, you can think of the search for attributes inherited from a parent class as depth-first, left-to-right, not searching twice in the same class where there is an overlap in the hierarchy.

Which means that `common_test_case.CommonTestCase` will be searched then `unittest.TestCase`. If there is no id function in `common_test_case.CommonTestCase` things should work as if it is only derived from `unittest.TestCase`. If you feel the need to add an `id` function to the `CommonTestCase`, something like this (if really necessary):

```
def id(self):
  if issubclass(self,unittest.TestCase):
    return super(unittest.TestCase,self).id()
```

Comment: In my case, test methods are not called directly from test, but rather inherited from another class (see the detailed description in question). That's why this approach will output the class not of test that is currently ran, but of the test the method was defined in (and that is not what I want). Am I missing anything?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation in the update. Though it is not the case that `common_test_case.CommonTestCase` is inherited from `unittest.TestCase`. I am not doing so, to prevent  `CommonTestCase` tests from running on their own (using recipe from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1323554/8554766), actually).

Comment: That shouldn't matter unless your common test defines an id function.

Comment: Indeed, it works (should have tested is, from the very beginning). `self.id().split('.')[-1]` — gives a test name; `self.id().split('.')[-2]` — gives a class from which test  **was called**. And no _hacky_ [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) calls!. Thanks for your answer and multiple elaborations.

Answer (score 0):

The solution [I've found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53153512/8554766) (that does the trick, so far):

```
import inspect

class_called_from = inspect.stack()[1][0].f_locals['self'].__class__.__name__
```

I'm still wondering, though, if there is a "clearer" method, or if this is possible to achieve using [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#module-logging) module.

---

Recipes, based on [West's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55645843/8554766) (tested on Python 3.6.1):

```
test_name = self.id().split('.')[-1]
class_called_from = self.id().split('.')[-2]
```